# Is $B(H \otimes K)$ generated by $B(H) \otimes B(K)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, operator-algebras

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and $H \otimes K$ their Hilbert space tensor product.

Given $S \in B(H)$ and $T \in B(K)$, there is a unique operator $S \otimes T \in B(H \otimes K)$ such that
$$(S \otimes T) (h \otimes k) = Sh \otimes Tk, \quad h\in H, k \in K.$$

Is the following equality true?

$$B(H \otimes K) = \overline{\text{span}}\{S \otimes T: S \in B(H), T \in B(K)\}$$

If so, how can one show this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to be careful when you write $B(H)\otimes B(K)$ because, as a C$^*$-algebra, $B(H)$ is not nuclear and so there not a unique tensor norm. The product also makes sense as  von Neumann algebras, in which case it is unique; the latter is the most common interpretation (but then the set in your title and the set in your question are not the same).

The equality is true if you take the sot-closure. In that case the closed span is $B(H)\otimes B(K)$ as von Neumann algebras, and you have $$(B(H)\otimes B(K))'=B(H)'\otimes B(K)'=\mathbb C\otimes \mathbb C,$$ so $B(H)\otimes B(K)=(B(H)\otimes B(K))''=(\mathbb C\otimes \mathbb C)'=B(H\otimes K)$. Alternatively, one can show that rank-one operators in $B(H\otimes K)$ are in $B(H)\odot B(K)$, and so the sot-closure will be everything.

With norm closure, on the other hand, there is no equality. This can be easily seen when both $H,K$ are  separable, from the fact that the C$^*$-algebra $\overline{\operatorname{span}} B(H)\odot B(K)$ has several ideals ($K(H)\otimes B(K)$, $B(H)\otimes K(K)$, $K(H)\otimes K(K)$) while $B(H\otimes K)$ has only one.

---

**Edit:** When $H$ is not separable the idea in the last paragraph still works, by noting that  the  ideals of $B(H\otimes K)$  are generated by the operators with rank at most a certain cardinality, while either $K(H)\otimes B(K)$ or $B(H)\otimes K(K)$ will have operators with rank of full cardinality.

Comment: This last paragraph is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: And a month later, the middle paragraph is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks again!

Comment: Nice to hear! $ $

Comment: Maybe a quick question: If $C \subseteq B(H)$ is convex, then are the $\sigma$-weak and the weak closure of $C$ equal? Because in my notes the von Neumann algebra tensor product is defined as the $\sigma$-weak closure of $B(H) \odot B(K)$. I already know that the strong and the weak closure of a convex set coincide.

Comment: Indeed, given two locally convex topologies, the closures of a convex set w.r.t. each of the topologies coincide.  (The simplest way to show this that I know of is by making use of the fact that in a locally convex vector space a compact and a closed set can be strictly seperated by a functional. Then one can show that the closure w.r.t. the first topology is closed w.r.t. the second topology).

Comment: @J.Becker Does this hold this general? If $X$ is a locally convex space for $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ and $C \subseteq X$ is convex, then the $\tau_1$-closure and the $\tau_2$-closure of $C$ coincide?

Comment: @J.Becker: that makes no sense. Even without talking about operator algebras, consider $C$ to be the polynomials,  with the locally convex topologies given by the $2$-norm on $[0,1]$ and the infinity-norm on $[0,1]$. In one case the completion is $L^2[0,1]$ and in the other it is $C[0,1]$. In operator algebras, take any separable infinite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra $A\subset B(H)$. Then the unit ball of $A$ is norm-closed, but its sot-closure is the unit ball of $A''$, which is necessarily larger.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot the condition that the induced dual spaces must coincide for my claim to hold. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, let's delete our comments so we don't clutter the comment section needlessly.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Nice answer. One small caveat though: If $H$ is not separable, there is more than one non-trivial closed ideal in $B(H)$. So, for your last argument to work you need to impose some separability conditions on $H$ and $K$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: that's for noticing. I have amended the argument.