# Minimal tensor product of $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ and $K$ be two Hilbert spaces. We have a natural inclusion of $B(H)\otimes B(K)$ into $B(H\otimes_2 K)$ where $H\otimes_2 K$ is the Hilbertian tensor product. Is $B(H)\otimes B(K)$ dense in $B(H\otimes_2 K)$?

Comment: Just a quick question / comment: you mention minimal tensor product in the question title, but never in the question itself: by $B(H)\otimes B(K)$, you mean $B(H)\otimes_{min} B(K)$, right?

Comment: Ujan! No! The closure of $B(H)\otimes B(K)$ in $B(H\otimes_2 K)$ is denoted by $B(H)\otimes_{min}B(K)$.

Comment: The answer is no (if $H$ and $K$ are infinite-dimensional), and I am pretty sure this has been answered before on this site. This can be seen by looking at the ideal structure of $B(H)\otimes_\min B(K)$.

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician Yes, of course, you are right: a mistake from my side. So, the question asks, (when) is $B(H)\otimes_{min} B(K)$ equal to $B(H\otimes_2 K)$, right? Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician: take a look at this [question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928574/is-bh-otimes-k-generated-by-bh-otimes-bk/3928977#3928977) (in particular the paragraph *With  norm closure...* and see if it answers your question; if it does, I'll close as duplicate.

Comment: @ You can close it. Your suggestion works.